# how to recognize an same image with different size ?

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction

We as human, could recognize these [two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uaRu.jpg) as same image :

[image]

In computer, it will be easy to recognize these two image if they are in the same size, so we have to make Preprocessing stage or step before recognize it, like scaling, but if we look deeply to scaling process, we will know that it's not an efficient way.

Now, could you help me to find some way to convert images into objects that doesn't deal with size or pixel location, to be input for recognition method ?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several ideas:

- Let the image have several color thresholds. This way you get large
  areas of the same color. The shapes of those areas can be traced with
  curves which are math. If you do this for the larger and the smaller
  one and see if the curves match.
- Try to define key spots in the area.    I don't know for sure how
  this works but you can look up face    detection algoritms. In such
  an algoritm there is a math equation for    how a face should look.
  If you define enough object in such algorithms    you can define
  multiple objects in the images to see if the object    match on the
  same spots.
- And you could see if the [predator    algorithm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GhNXHCQGsM) can accept images
  of multiple size. If so your problem    is solved.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but do you think that it will work with binary images(Black and White) ?

Comment: I dont see a reason why the last 2 wouldn't work. But the first one needs a little adeption to grayscale thresholds. But should be fine. But these are just rough ideas.

Comment: I think you can trace the image with curves, so that you make a kind of vector image from it. Then you check if the vectors are alike, if the curves have almost the same numbers in it.

Comment: i did it before and unfortunately it was failed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you assume that human's brain recognize image in computationally effective way, which is rather not true. this algorithm is so complicated that we did not find it. It also takes a large part of your brain to deal with visual data.

When it comes to software there are some scale(or affine) invariant algorithms. One of such algorithms is LeNet 5 neural network.